# Background grows and shrinks on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a mockup site over at http://cphn.cf/peachhatalt and there is an issue where if I scroll up and down on mobile, the background image will flick between bigger and smaller sizes ( by about say 10-20%)

I have a video here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLTwdayo7cs

and code here:

```
padding: 0 0 0 10px;
background-position: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/xCo0n9j.png") center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

any help would be 'preciated

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by flick between bigger and smaller sizes.. Is it possible the scroll bar is affecting the size as you scroll?

Comment: in the video that I linked it shows how it just suddenly expands the background image

Comment: I watched the video, but it seems to me that it is adjusting when the you scroll and when you stop scrolling. And it is a very minor adjustment. Nothing like 10-20%. I believe it is working correctly since you are using 'background-size: cover;'

Comment: it works as it is supposed, even on your video

Comment: Is this still a problem? In the video, it looks like you're zooming in and out a bit when scrolling. The text on top of the background changes size too.